# DBFlow listen when query finish

Tags: android, orm, dbflow

Hello guys i've read the documentation of DBFlow - ORM android database library , but i was wondering what is the right way to listen when a query finish it's work.
For example i've got insert and want to know if the insert is successful and when exactly finish.

[DBFlow Library](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **`Transactions`**. and transactions when executed have 2 callbacks. **`success`** and **`error`** where you can do further processing. 
For example:

```
 transaction
    .success(new Transaction.Success() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(Transaction transaction) {
          // called post-execution on the UI thread.
       }
   })
   .error(new Transaction.Error() {
       @Override
       public void onError(Transaction transaction, Throwable error) {
          // call if any errors occur in the transaction.
       }
   });
```

Check following link for more details:

[Storing data using DBFlow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage2/StoringData.md)